# Make the table in bootstrap expand to the full height of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the table in my bootstrap site expand to the full height of the current page, but what ever I do it only expands to about half the page and not any further.

Not sure how to accomplish this. SO I posted my table below if you need any more information let me know.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <style rel="stylesheet" src="./css/style.css"></style>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script rel="text/JavaScript">
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var height = h / rows.length;
      rows[i].style.height = String(height) + 'px';
  }
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered ">
     <thead>
          <tr style="height:100%">
            <th>Category One</th>
            <th>Category Two</th>
            <th>Category Three</th>
            <th>Category Four</th>
            <th>Category Five</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">100</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">100</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">100</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">100</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">100</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">200</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">200</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">200</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">200</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">200</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">300</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">300</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">300</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">300</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">300</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">400</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">400</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">400</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">400</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">400</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#">500</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">500</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">500</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">500</a></td>
            <td><a href="#">500</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I am guessing that you want the table rows to expand to a percentage of the window height, based on the number of rows. Here is a fairly simple way to do that using JavaScript / jQuery:

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
var rows = $('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var height = h / rows.length;
    $(rows[i]).css('height', String(height) + 'px');
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0as562at/) is a jsfiddle which shows it in action.  The height is not perfect, but it is a decent starting point.  Is this what you are looking for?

Edit:

Is the code throwing any errors in the console? One possibility is that jQuery may not included.  If that is the case, here is a pure javascript solution:

```
var h = window.innerHeight;
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var height = h / rows.length;
    rows[i].style.height = String(height) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this script in to my HTML document and it still did not affect the height of each of the rows.

Comment: I edited the answer with a pure javascript solution.  If this still does not work, please provide some additional details if possible; see if the console log is throwing any errors (use "Developer Tools", which can usually be accessed by an "F12" hotkey).  Also, what browser are you using, and are you including any additional CSS or JS files?  Does the jsfiddle (included in the answer) accurately display the rows as you would like?

Comment: I have the bootstrap and query cdn with a style sheet with just a background color.

Comment: Bootstrap requires jQuery in order to run.  You have included jQuery in your header ***after*** including bootstrap, which may cause bootstrap to fail.  Try importing jQuery first and see if that helps.